# convert from markdown to html using Clojure or ClojureScript, including tables

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

[markdown-clj](https://github.com/yogthos/markdown-clj) seems to work well but does not convert markdown tables. I do understand that tables are not an official part of the markdown specification.

So I am now using [Showdown](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown) via CLJSJS, for which there's a convenient [example](https://github.com/cljsjs/packages/wiki/Using-Packages), repeated here:

```
(defn convert-to-html [markdown]
  (let [converter (js/Showdown.converter.)]    
    (.makeHtml converter markdown)))
```

From the Showdown documentation what you need to do to have tables converted as well is to *turn on the option `tables`*. How would I do this in the ClojureScript code above?

**EDIT**
Note that the above syntax was correct at the time this question was asked. However you now need to:

```
(js/showdown.Converter.)
```

Note that both `showdown` and `Converter` have changed their capitalisation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read up on JavaScript [interop](http://www.spacjer.com/blog/2014/09/12/clojurescript-javascript-interop/).

Looking at the Showdown [docs](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown#setting-options) you got a few ways to enable table parsing.

Globally:

> showdown.setOption('optionKey', 'value');

```
(.setOption js/showdown "tables" true)
```

Locally:

> var converter = new showdown.Converter({optionKey: 'value'});

```
(let [converter (js/showdown.Converter. #js {:tables true})]
  ..)
```

Note the `#js`, a short hand for [clj->js](https://crossclj.info/fun/cljs.core.cljs/clj-%3Ejs.html), which takes care of converting ClojureScript values to JavaScript.

> var converter = new showdown.Converter();
>   converter.setOption('optionKey', 'value');

```
(let [converter (js/showdown.Converter.)
      _ (.setOption converter "tables" true)]
  ..)
```

Comment: Setting in the constructor doesn't seem to have any effect. And for the `.setOption` I get "Uncaught TypeError: converter.setOption is not a function".

Comment: Apparently the Showdown version in the cljsjs repo is quite ancient. 0.4.0 vs 1.4.2. [Updating](https://github.com/cljsjs/packages/wiki/Creating-Packages) a cljsjs package is usually pretty straight forward though.

Comment: 1.4.2 should be in the cljsjs repo in the next couple of days, watch this [PR](https://github.com/cljsjs/packages/pull/625/commits/152978c1f35ee9d5a1d13f967a8fc4cd91da29d1). Updated the answer as the namespace changed slightly.

Comment: I've now tried the latest one: `[cljsjs/showdown "1.4.2-0"]`, but still get the same problems.

Comment: I can only assume you still got the old version active, please double check. Just tested it again with a clean slate without any issue. I have put the log of my REPL tests in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/edannenberg/ff1a2c7e0994ddbe2855cf94ceddc4cc)

Comment: Thanks for that. Got rid of .m2 for Showdown, using Incognito, lein clean, lein deps,  (many times) invalidated IDEA indexes. Am now always getting 'Showdown is not defined'. So that's something. Will try again tomorrow...

Comment: I have `:require [cljsjs.showdown]` up the top of the file but always get 'Showdown is not defined' at `(js/Showdown.converter.)`

Comment: The namespace changed at one point after 0.4.0, it's lower case now and converter now with upper case C:  `(js/showdown.Converter.)`